# config.php register/login system Undefined index: config

Tags: php

Ok so i m making a new login/register thing and i got error prety quick can anyone help me whats wrong please? i m watching a tutorial and doing this cuz i m new at php and it works all fine to the guy that is making this..

the error i get : **Notice: Undefined index: config in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsistem\classes\Config.php on line 5**

my init.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS ['confg'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'lr'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';

});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
?>
```

here is my sanitize.php

```
<?php
function escape($string) {
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');    
}
?>
```

my index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

echo Config::get('mysql/host'); //127.0.0.1 
?>
```

and config.php

```
<?php
class Config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach ($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you have misspelled config in your init.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a tiny mistake, take a look at your init.php:

```
$GLOBALS ['confg'] = array(
```

it should be 'config' instead of 'confg' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in confg in init.php

```
$GLOBALS ['config'] = array(
```

config.php line 5 suggested that the problem was related to the array.

Comment: @Francodi beats me :)